# Enabling right click copy for ipython plots?

Tags: matplotlib, ms-word, ipython

Is there a way to enable matplotlib/ipython so I can right click my plots (in Chrome) and copy then paste elsewhere such as MS Word etc?

I know I can code and save to image etc, but often when I am playing around investigating data it would be very useful to just copy / paste into a document for safekeeping and reports.

*EDIT: Problem seems to be using MS Word (2010) and any dynamic image from any Browser (IE/Chrome), If I use other progs like Write it works okay.  I found some advice to change the "Pasting from other programs" option in Word settings but it has no effect.*

*Also another [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572244/cant-paste-dynamically-generated-image-from-any-browser-to-ms-word) says the problem is based on the contents of the "HTML Format" format stored in the clipboard.*

*Guess I need to post this question elsewhere seems to be an MS Word issue!*

Comment: Another alternative is simply to use the notebook itself as a report, there are [some formatting options here](https://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#formatting-and-conversion-projects).

Comment: I would also like to see a solution, pasting generated content into a LibreOffice writer doc works fine. After that you can paste it into Word 2013... Annoyingly laborious.

Comment: I have resorted to right click, copy, paste into write/wordpad, then copy from there again and paste into word.

Comment: Further to above the problem was MS Words default behaviour for paste operations which looks at the url source meta data rather than the image data in the clipboard.  Using paste special and selecting a bitmap type solves the issue.

Answer (score 16):

If you control-shift right click, it'll return to the standard Chrome context menu instead of the iPython one.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ipython notebook (which I guess you must be, since you're mentioning using Chrome), you can just right-click on your graph and choose `Copy Image` then paste into whatever software

Comment: The problem is that doesn't work, I wish it did!  (I've just discovered the problem seems to be MS Word, if I use 'write' I can paste without any issue)

Comment: This worked for me and saved me a lot of times. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: the below answer doesn't always work anymore (something changed I think), but there is another stack overflow question here with an answer that is working, namely using Ctrl+Alt+V to do a paste-special:
[Jupyter Notebook: How to copy paste image into MS word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313128/jupyter-notebook-how-to-copy-paste-image-into-ms-word/42656387#42656387)

---

A straight Ctrl+V will generally fail in MS Office for this purpose, but there is the "paste image" option which is what is working for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop worked for me using Chrome and MS Word on macOS.