# Jupyter Notebook: How to copy paste image into MS word?

Tags: clipboard, jupyter-notebook

I tried to copy the image and paste them into MS word, but it didn't work.

I'm not sure if this is my problem, or the word's problem?

The images are at:
https://cdn.rawgit.com/cqcn1991/Wind-Speed-Analysis/master/output_HTML/marham.html#5.3-Sectoral-Comaprison

[image]

The paste result (in MS Word), it's done by CTRL+C, CTRL+V:

[image]

I can only paste the text, not the image.

I experiment it with Medium and another web app. Medium works exactly like MS Word, while another is able to paste. I think the underlying problem may be that the image in Jupyter Notebook is too deep in divs? so it get escaped in Word?

Comment: Copy how? What happened instead it being pasted? "It didn't work" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: @nitind just updated. I can only paste the text, not the images.

Comment: I have the same problem. I press copy, or copy picture, in the jupyter notebook, but it doesn't actually go to my clipboard. When I try to paste in, e.g., onedrive, it just pastes whatever I recently had copied before I attempted to copy the picture.

Comment: Only workaround I have right now is to paste into mspaint and then immediately cut and paste out of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the issue you raised on github:
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1496

I can get this to work if after copying from the notebook I do Ctrl+Alt+V (shortcut for paste-special) and then select either "bitmap" or "device independent bitmap" from the dialog that pops up

Answer (score 10):

Right Click on image and select "Create New View for Output"
A new image file will appear. From there you can select the image and using the shortcuts  CTRL + C and CTRL + V onto your document.

Answer (score 2):

Add *plt.figure(facecolor='w')* before you plot any figures because the default face color is black.

Then, just right click on the figure and past as normal figures.

Answer (score 2):

Applicable for Jupyter version >= 7:

You can circumvent the Jupyter context menu via **Shift + Right Click** to get the browser's own context menu (it is mentioned on the bottom of the Jupyter context menu)

Answer (score 1):

You can drag the image on to OneNote and from there your copy/paste options are available for transfer into Word.

Comment: Maybe you could flesh out this answer or try breaking it down into steps.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for posting on a dated thread but I was having a similar problem.

I had been using Jupyter in PyCharm and was unable to copy and paste it at all. I then found that if I opened the notebook in a browser (Chrome) using the localhost link then I could right click and copy and paste, or save, the image as you normally would be able to for any other.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible both on Jupyter lab and Jupyter notebook to right-click on the graph and save it in .png format. Then you could use the image elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter lab disables the browser right-click menu and implements its own menu. In Google Chrome you can download any extension which enables right-click. Then you can simply right-click on any inline figure and copy the image.

This is the extension that I use. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-right-click/hompjdfbfmmmgflfjdlnkohcplmboaeo

But the simplest way is to create a new new view for the output, but for longer notebooks it takes time.

Answer (score 0):

Quite surprisingly, drag and drop worked for me (Ubuntu 22, drop into a Microsoft365 powerpoint opened in my browser).

Answer (score -5):

Right click on the image in your Notebook and choose 'Save image as ...'. You may now insert the saved image in your MS word document.

Comment: Hello @Niek and welcome to Stack Overflow. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. In the meanwhile, perhaps you could expand on your answer so that your solution does not require any further clarification from the asker.

Comment: Jupyter (lab at least) intercepts right-clicks and has its own context menu that doesn't give this option.